# Error - NLTK WordLemmatizer is giving alphabets instead of lemmatized words

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, wordnet, lemmatization

```
from nltk import word_tokenize
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
def lemmatize_words(row):
    lem_words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in row]
    return (lem_words)

df['Lemmatized Text'] = df.Stopwords.apply(lemmatize_words)
```

The above code is iterating over all characters in the row. I want it to consider the row as a list.
[Following is my dataframe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n65OU.jpg)
I want to pass Stopwords Column to the lemmatizer. The current output is present in Lemmatized Text column

Comment: How does `row` that get passed to `lemmatize_words` look like?

Comment: Did you define the stop words?

Comment: @Anwarvic That row refers to every row in the "Stopwords" column in the dataframe. Pls refer to the image that I have attached.

Comment: @Darkknight I have already removed the stopwords from the text. Now I want to lemmatize the resulting text. The "Stopwords" in the above code refers to the "Stopwords" column in the dataframe.

Comment: Pandas dataframes do not store arrays. Your stopword column is just a string.

Comment: I think the problem lies when saving the `stopwords` to the dataframe. It was saved as a string, not a list. Double-check that or post it in the questin

Comment: @Anwarvic Yeah, the stopwords were stored as strings instead of List. Thx for your help